# fedora 20 yum update error

Tags: fedora, yum, fedora20, dnf

I need to update my system and I just did a **sudo yum update**, and got the following errors.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-1.4.3-1.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libcdio.so.15(CDIO_15)(64bit)
Error: Package: gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-1.4.3-1.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libcdio.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: gstreamer-plugins-ugly-0.10.19-18.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libcdio.so.15(CDIO_15)(64bit)
Error: Package: librtmp-2.4-3.20131205.gitdc76f0a.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libgcrypt.so.20()(64bit)
Error: Package: gstreamer-plugins-ugly-0.10.19-18.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-rawhide)
           Requires: libcdio.so.15()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried installing libcdio with, **sudo yum install libcdio** because of the dependency error as seen above, but it appears to be already installed.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: ftp.nluug.nl
 * rpmfusion-free-rawhide: ftp.nluug.nl
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide: ftp.nluug.nl
 * updates: ftp.nluug.nl
Package libcdio-0.90-3.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Please also **note** that I have tried these two commands.
**yum clean all** and 
**yum clean metadata**

### Edit

when I try and install rpmfusion for fedora 20, it wouldn't let me, since it already has a the fedora 21 repo already installed.

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    package rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch (which is newer than rpmfusion-free-release-20-1.noarch) is already installed
    file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-latest from install of rpmfusion-free-release-20-1.noarch conflicts with file from package rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch
    file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-rawhide from install of rpmfusion-free-release-20-1.noarch conflicts with file from package rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch
    file /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo from install of rpmfusion-free-release-20-1.noarch conflicts with file from package rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch
    file /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo from install of rpmfusion-free-release-20-1.noarch conflicts with file from package rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch
    file /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free.repo from install of rpmfusion-free-release-20-1.noarch conflicts with file from package rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rpmfusion-free-rawhide` is targeting `fc21`. Your system is `fc20`. As such the `rpmfusion-free-rawhide` RPMs are depending on versions of system packages newer than what your default repositories (and your installed system) have available.

You can either upgrade your system to `fc21` or find an rpmfusion repository that targets `fc20`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Etan, but when I install fedora 20's rpmfusion repo it doesn't allow it since it already has fedora 21's repo installed. Please see edits on the original question. Thanks

Comment: @arithran Remove the newer package first then install the older one.